# Dynamically update display order using coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I’m a self-taught, hobby-coder volunteering for a small, local non-profit organization and am updating its website admin section using coldfusion.

A section of it is used to display the volunteers in an assigned order on the front end. I’ve added a “Display” column in the table where I set the order number of how the volunteers will be displayed. (1 is first, 2 is second, etc.)

I’d like to be able to dynamically rearrange the display order when updating or adding a record. Typically I’d bring in a senior programmer to do this but that’s not within the budget, so I thought I’d give it a shot.

**Example:**

1 = 1

2 = 2

3 = 3

Currently if I change 3 to 1, I get two 1s and 3 goes away. (expected)

1 = 1 (used to be 3)

1 = 1

2 = 2

I’d like the update to move all records below it to update as well.

*(If I move 3 to 1)*

1 = 1 (used to be 3)

2 = 2 (used to be 1)

3 = 3 (used to be 2)

OR

*(If I move 3 to 2)*

1 = 1

2 = 2 (used to be 3)

3 = 3 (used to be 2)

Currently I’m just updating each record individually, but that’s clearly not ideal, especially when the volunteer list grows into the teens or more.

I’ve searched for hours looking for guidance on how to do this but am at a loss as to where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here’s the update form code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Display">Display Order</label>
                <select name="display" class="form-control form-control-lg" required>
                    <option value="">Select Display Order</option>
                    <cfoutput query="GetBioDisplay"><option value="#GetBioDisplay.display#">#GetBioDisplay.display#</option></cfoutput>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Here’s the update query:

```
            <cfquery name = "UpdateProfile" datasource="#dsn#">
                UPDATE DBO.PROFILE
                    SET firstname  =  '#form.firstname#', 
                    lastname       =  '#form.lastname#', 
                    title          =  '#form.title#',
                    email          =  '#form.email#',
                    display        =  '#form.display#', 
                    Picture        =  '#form.picture#',
                    profile        = '#form.profile#',
                    credentials    = '#form.credentials#' 
                    WHERE ID       =   #url.id#
            </cfquery>
```

Here’s the query I use for the user / front end:

```
            <cfquery name="GetProfile" datasource="#request.dsn#">
                SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, TITLE, EMAIL, 
                    PICTURE, DISPLAY, PROFILE, CREDENTIALS
                        FROM DBO.PROFILE
                            ORDER BY DISPLAY
            </cfquery>
```

Comment: OT: 1. Use `<cfqueryparam>` before something bad happens. 2. Have you considered sorting using something like "Datatables.net" ? 3. I am unclear what you need. Can you provide an outline of the before and after data.

Comment: I'd recommend more than just `cfqueryparam`s for this query. It is screaming to be injected and causing undesirable things to happen. I'd also do some heavy validation on the inputs. And also make sure that the ColdFusion user your using only has the permissions it needs. `SA` is a bad account to use for _anything_ not on the server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE/WHEN` conditional statement in your `WHERE` clause to update to the correct value, regardless of the direction you're moving the record. You only need to pass two values: The position you're updating from (`url.id`) and the position you're updating to (`form.position`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e9bef/7)
**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    display int NOT NULL,
    item varchar(2000) NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO test (display, item)
VALUES 
    (1,'a')
  , (2,'b')
  , (3,'c')
  , (4,'d')
  , (5,'e')
  , (6,'f')
  , (7,'g')
  , (8,'h')
  , (9,'i')
  , (10,'j')
;
```

**Query - Order Up**:

```
/* Move 8 to 4 - UP */

DECLARE @updDisp int = 8
DECLARE @updTo int = 4

UPDATE test
SET display = (CASE 
    WHEN display = @updDisp THEN @updTo 
    WHEN @updDisp < @updTo THEN display-1
    WHEN @updDisp > @updTo THEN display+1
    END
)
WHERE 
    ( display BETWEEN @updDisp AND @updTo )
    OR 
    ( display BETWEEN @updTo AND @updDisp )
;
```

**RESULTS**

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY display 


| display | item |
|---------|------|
|       1 |    a |
|       2 |    b |
|       3 |    c |
|       4 |    h |
|       5 |    d |
|       6 |    e |
|       7 |    f |
|       8 |    g |
|       9 |    i |
|      10 |    j |
```

**Query - Order Down**:

```
/* Move 4 to 8 - DOWN */

DECLARE @updDisp int = 4
DECLARE @updTo int = 8

UPDATE test
SET display = (CASE 
    WHEN display = @updDisp THEN @updTo 
    WHEN @updDisp < @updTo THEN display-1
    WHEN @updDisp > @updTo THEN display+1
    END
)
WHERE 
    ( display BETWEEN @updDisp AND @updTo )
    OR 
    ( display BETWEEN @updTo AND @updDisp )
```

**RESULTS**

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY display 


| display | item |
|---------|------|
|       1 |    a |
|       2 |    b |
|       3 |    c |
|       4 |    d |
|       5 |    e |
|       6 |    f |
|       7 |    g |
|       8 |    h |
|       9 |    i |
|      10 |    j |
```

So your CF code would look something like this:

```
//// process and validate form variables here ////
local.updDisp = url.id
local.updTo   = form.display
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

<cfquery name="UpdateProfile" datasource="#dsn#">
    UPDATE DBO.PROFILE
    SET display = (
        CASE 
            WHEN display = #val(local.updDisp)# THEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updTo#">
            WHEN #val(local.updDisp)# < #val(local.updTo)# THEN display-1
            WHEN #val(local.updDisp)# > #val(local.updTo)# THEN display+1
        END
    )
    WHERE ( display BETWEEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updDisp#"> AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updTo#"> )
        OR 
        ( display BETWEEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updTo#"> AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updDisp#"> )
</cfquery>
```

I'm not sure if you can use `cfqueryparam` in a `CASE` statement inside of a `SET`, and I don't have a way to test. Regardless, since we know we always should be working with `integers`, then the `val()` function should offer the same protection that the `cfqueryparam` does in this instance.

I'm also of the somewhat more paranoid mindset when it comes to user input. `cfqueryparam` is very good at what it does, but it doesn't protect against all issues. I'd still recommend doing some sort of pre-processing before you allow those values anywhere near your database.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af0c8/1 << I changed the dataset to more accurately reflect the data you're using, so you could see this query is only concerned with the `display` column. I also added an example of how you could handle it if someone tried to enter an order that was beyond the maximum size of the list.

Comment: Looks a bit beyond my skill set but I'll certainly give it a shot. If I'm seeing this right, you're running 3 queries back-to-back and then displaying the results with another query? I'm also assuming they would run after the initial UPDATE query?

Comment: @MJRoz It should just be the one `UPDATE` query getting run to do the actual update you're aiming for. The `WHERE` clause is only limiting the records that would be included in the `UPDATE`. None of the others should be affected. Most of my example code was really just setting up what you had and then demonstrating what you're updating.

Comment: That's what I though/tried originally but got the syntax error below so I stopped there. **Message Content Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'.
The error occurred on line 40.**

Comment: @MJRoz Sorry. Error in the query. It shouldn't have had the `ID =`. I fixed it.

Comment: That did it! I'm very grateful. Thank you. Any thoughts on how to use this on an INSERT when adding a new record? I am inserting #form.display# which will duplicate whatever display number exists. (e.g. If I add a new 3, the result will give me two 3s.)  I need to take the existing 3 (display number) if there is one, and change it to 4 (or whatever) and push any number below it down by one. 3 becomes 4, 4 becomes 5, etc. I attempted to adapt the UPDATE query you created but failed miserably.

Comment: Since you're both inserting and updating records, you'll have to do an `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`, but the query I wrote won't work for that, unless you `INSERT` to the last position and then move it with an `UPDATE`. Or you could use a trigger on the table, but that's a little more complicated and a lot less visible (and easy to lose on a migration or table change).

Comment: Since you aren't working with a lot of records, it may be just as easy to simply `UPDATE` the `display` of every row that is >= your new record ( UPDATE dbo.profile SET display = display+1 WHERE display >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.updDisp#">. And then `INSERT` your new record. Do it inside a transaction, so it can roll back if it fails.

Comment: Perfect! I also used this on 'DELETE' by changing ( UPDATE dbo.profile SET display = **display+1** to **display-1** Appreciate all your help. :)

Comment: @MJRoz Good deal. Just make sure that it's doing what you want to the records you want before you go live with it. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Add a second update query

```
update dbo.profile
set display = display + 1
where display >= <cfqueryparam CFSQLType = "cf_sql_integer" value = "#form.display#">
and id <> <cfqueryparam CFSQLType = "cf_sql_integer" value = "#url.id#">
```

You should use query paramters in your other queries as well.  The way your current update query is written, it will throw an error on names like O'Malley.

**Edit Starts Here**
To allow the users to see they should see, change this

```
     <cfoutput query="GetBioDisplay">
     <option value="#GetBioDisplay.display#">#GetBioDisplay.display#
     </option>
     </cfoutput>
```

to this

```
     <cfoutput query="GetBioDisplay">
     <option value="#GetBioDisplay.display#">#GetBioDisplay.rownumber#
     </option>
     </cfoutput>
```

This will show users numbers such as 1,2,3, etc

Comment: This moves all records down by 1 spot including the record(s) below the one moved up. 
i.e. If I move position 4 to position 1, it moves 2 to 3, 3 to 4 - LEAVES 5 OPEN - and moves 5 to 6 instead of leaving 5 at 5.

I’d like to move the display at position 1 to let's say position 5 and have all the display 
numbers move up 1 position. Similarly if I move the display number from position 10 
to position 7, I want display number 9 to move to position 10, display number 8 to position 9, 
display number 7 to position 8 so previously positioned display number 10 can take place at position 7.

Comment: Are you sure it matters what the actual numbers are as long as they are in the correct order?

Comment: Hmmm... good thought. If it were just me maintaining the list, I'd be fine with it. I think it'll confuse the user maintaining it, however.